# Real-time data matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, real-time, matching

I have a set (integer) of input values and a set of expected values, e.g.

```
000033335502200008777
000033335552200007777
```

in this sample I have zero input, that should be ignored and groups of non-zero input:

```
3333
555
22
7777
```

input data could have

1. different length of group (550 and 555)
2. group shift (0055500 0555000)
3. wrong (but close) values (8777 and 7777)

for each such group I would like to have matching ratio like this:

```
3333 (100%)
555  (66.67%)
22 (100%)
7777 (75%)
```

Important point is that I need this ratio right after the processing of each group is finished:

```
first ratio after 8 values
second ratio after 11 values
third ratio after 13 values
fourth ratio after 21 values
```

**What algorithm/approach should I choose?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you get 75% for `555` vs `55`? Shouldn't it be either 66.67% or 150% (depending on which string is your input and which is the expectation)? Have you tried anything?

Comment: You're totally right, it should be 66,67%. First is the input and second is the expectation. I have tried to implement such matching by myself, but have no success with it. That's why I'm looking for some generic approach / well known algorithm.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing that people comparing gene sequences would/do use.  Have your tried googling algorithms for gene pattern matching or anything like it?

Comment: I haven't. But that's very good idea, thank you. Will search in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are some algorithms from computational biology and genetics that might be suited for fast numbers matching, and also in a field of sequence pattern mining.

Check "[A FAST](http://www.math.utah.edu/~palais/dnamath/patternmatching.pdf) Pattern Matching Algorithm" by S. S. Sheik, Sumit K. Aggarwal Anindya Poddar N. Balakrishnan,‡ and K. Sekar

Also, it appears like you could benefit from algorithms that look into matching between the components of the strings.

Some well known are [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm), and [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm). 
For direct string matching I suggest looking into [Jaro-Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) and Monge-Elkan.